# define a Height for the BottomAppBar like the Navigation Bar Height in a universal App

Tags: c#, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I want to change the Height of the BottomAppBar like the same Hight of the NavigationBar,this is my try:

```
    <Page.BottomAppBar>
        <CommandBar Background="#393185"
                Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Style="{Binding Source={StaticResource Ellipsis}}" Height="40" MinHeight="40">
            <CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>

                <AppBarButton Label="Cortana"
                          Icon="Microphone"
                          Foreground="White"  
                               MinHeight="40" Height="40"/>
             </CommandBar.PrimaryCommands>
     </CommandBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>
```

referincing this article:[CommandBar style](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/windows/apps/mt299118.aspx/)

and this is the result that I get:

[image]

as you can see I get an espace between my Grid and the BottomAppBar
so please is there any way to delete this Margin??
thanks for help

Update:
I have tried like this in the CommandBarOverflowPresenter:Styles.xaml

```
             <CommandBarOverflowPresenter x:Name="SecondaryItemsControl"
                  Style="{TemplateBinding CommandBarOverflowPresenterStyle}"
                  IsEnabled="False"
                  IsTabStop="False">
                <CommandBarOverflowPresenter.RenderTransform>
                  <TranslateTransform x:Name="OverflowContentTransform"/>
                </CommandBarOverflowPresenter.RenderTransform>
                <CommandBarOverflowPresenter.ItemContainerStyle>
                  <Style TargetType="FrameworkElement">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                    <Setter Property="Width" Value="NaN"/>
                   <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-10,0,0"/>
                  </Style>
                </CommandBarOverflowPresenter.ItemContainerStyle>
              </CommandBarOverflowPresenter>
```

and I have set the height and tha MinHeight to 40 like this:Page1.xaml

```
<CommandBar Background="#393185"
                Foreground="White"Height="40" MinHeight="40">
            <CommandBar.CommandBarOverflowPresenterStyle>
                <Style TargetType="CommandBarOverflowPresenter">
                    <Setter Property="Background"
                        Value="#00a0e3" ></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-10,0,0"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </CommandBar.CommandBarOverflowPresenterStyle>
  </CommandBar>
```

but I get always the same problem ,miss I anything in my code :(
thanks again for help

Comment: thanks Sir ganchito55 for the edit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried:

`<CommandBar Background="#393185"
            Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0" Height="40" MinHeight="40" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0">`

However when Height takes the 40 value, Visual Studio shows a gap between my grid and my commandbar. So I think that this control has a minimum height value and 40 is lower than this minimum value.

[image]

Comment: so should I modify the Minimum height value  in the CommandBar Style Sir?

Comment: @user3821206 I tried the value 48 and for me work well. You can try Height="48" MinHeight="48"

Comment: thanks Sir for your reply,but this is not what I want :(,I want to change the Height of bottomAppBar like the hight of the Navigation Bar that contains the Back Button,how can I put the right height and not have this margin with the Grid component thanks again

Comment: even with a Height =" 48" I get the same problem when running the app